# how to perform merge or join operation in R with two different dataframe size

Tags: r, dataframe

I have two data frames A and B with different size where I am trying to implement either left join or merge data frames based on the certain conditions. Can anyone help me on how to join two tables in R. I am using a1, a2 and b1,b2 to join the two data frames?

```
df A
a1 a2   a3         a4
1  1   2017-04-25  2017-05-24
1  1   2017-05-25  2017-06-24
2  3   2017-04-25  2017-05-24
3  4   2017-04-25  2017-05-24
4  5   2017-04-25  2017-05-24
4  5   2017-05-25  2017-06-24
4  7   2017-04-25  2017-05-24
5  8   2017-04-25  2017-05-24
5  8   2017-05-25  2017-06-24


df B
b1  b2  b3         b4         b5
1   1  2017-04-20  2017-05-02  M
2   3  2017-03-27  2017-05-19  A
3   4  2017-04-20  2017-05-22  B
4   5  2017-04-21  2017-05-12  N
4   7  2017-05-02  2017-05-09  L
5   8  2017-05-15  2017-05-04  U
```

Dimension of the first dataframe

```
> dim(A)
   [1] 506335      5
```

dimensions of the second data frame

```
> dim(B)
[1] 716776      6

tried below left join in R

left_join(A, B, a1=b1, a2 = b2,  a3 > b3 , a4 < b4)
```

Error:

```
Error in common_by(by, x, y) : object 'b3' not found

Tried merge operation operation but getting below error
merge(A,B,by=c("a1","a2", "a3 > b3" , "a4 < b4"))
```

Error:

```
Error in ungroup_grouped_df(x) : 
      object 'dplyr_ungroup_grouped_df' not found
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to do with the `a3>b3` terms. It looks as if you want to merge by the first two columns, and then perhaps filter based on a comparison of the dates.  Perhaps start with `merge(A,B,by.x=c("a1","a2"),by.y=c("b1","b2"),all.x=TRUE)` and then work out what to do with the date columns.

Comment: @vinaykaragod Have any of the answers below helped you out? If so, please accept an answer. If not, please update your question to ask for the further help you need.

Answer (score 2):

From what I gather you are trying to

1- Merge the DF by their first two columns

2- Filter the DF where this conditions are met a3 > b3 , a4 < b4

```
require(dplyr)
DF <- left_join(A,B, a1=b1, a2=b2) %>% filter(a3 > b3 , a4 < b4)
```

Answer (score 2):

As Andrew Gustar has commented, you are trying to merge and filter at the same time. Instead, do the merge first, then the filter. It also looks like you're working with dates, so they need to be formatted correctly.

The code below can all be carried out in one chain, but I've broken it down to make it easier to understand.

For example, using the tidyverse `dplyr` and `lubridate` packages:

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

# load in your data

textA <- "a1 a2   a3         a4
1  1   2017-04-25  2017-05-24
1  1   2017-05-25  2017-06-24
2  3   2017-04-25  2017-05-24
3  4   2017-04-25  2017-05-24
4  5   2017-04-25  2017-05-24
4  5   2017-05-25  2017-06-24
4  7   2017-04-25  2017-05-24
5  8   2017-04-25  2017-05-24
5  8   2017-05-25  2017-06-24"

textB <- "b1  b2  b3         b4         b5
1   1  2017-04-20  2017-05-02  M
2   3  2017-03-27  2017-05-19  A
3   4  2017-04-20  2017-05-22  B
4   5  2017-04-21  2017-05-12  N
4   7  2017-05-02  2017-05-09  L
5   8  2017-05-15  2017-05-04  U"

# make dataframes
dfA <- read.table(text = textA, header = T)
dfB <- read.table(text = textB , header = T)

# now do the merging - when merging on more than one column, combine them using c
dfout <- left_join(x = dfA, y = dfB, by = c("a1" = "b1", "a2" = "b2"))

# now switch your a3, a4, b3, and b4 columns to dates format using the ymd function
dfout <- dfout %>% mutate_at(vars(a3:b4), ymd)

# finally the filtering
dfout <- dfout %>% filter(a3 > b3)
```

This returns:

```
  a1 a2         a3         a4         b3         b4 b5
1  1  1 2017-04-25 2017-05-24 2017-04-20 2017-05-02  M
2  1  1 2017-05-25 2017-06-24 2017-04-20 2017-05-02  M
3  2  3 2017-04-25 2017-05-24 2017-03-27 2017-05-19  A
4  3  4 2017-04-25 2017-05-24 2017-04-20 2017-05-22  B
5  4  5 2017-04-25 2017-05-24 2017-04-21 2017-05-12  N
6  4  5 2017-05-25 2017-06-24 2017-04-21 2017-05-12  N
7  5  8 2017-05-25 2017-06-24 2017-05-15 2017-05-04  U
```

Note that filtering again (using code below) on `a4 < b4` returns a dataframe with 0 rows.

```
dfout %>% mutate_at(vars(a3:b4), ymd) %>% filter(a3 > b3) %>% filter(a4 < b4)
```